# Virtualbox and Serial Port permissions for Windows10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, virtualbox, permissions, serial-port

I am using Windows10[HostOS]. I wanna create a virtual environment(windows7[GuestOS]) on Oracle VirtualBox(Ver5.2.18 r124319). However, I get the following error.

How can I check this permission?

```
[MyPC Settings]
 HostOS Serial port  :COM3
 GuestOS Serial port :COM1

[VirtualBox Error]
 Cannot open host device 'COM3' for read/write access. Check the permissions of that device (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED).
 [Detail]
 Exit Code : E_FAIL (0x80004005)
 Component: ConsoleWrap
 InterFace: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Comment: What do you have on COM3?

Comment: @harrymc it's a Microcomputer board(16bit) with USB2.0.

Answer (score 0):

The port might be in use on the host. Here is how to find out.

- Download and install
  [WinObj](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/winobj)
- run WinObj and click on the left the entry named `GLOBAL??`
- Search for `COM3` on the right.
  The SymLink column will display a device name, perhaps `\Device\Serial2`.
- Download and install
  [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
- Run Process Explorer and open the search dialog via
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
  and type the serial device name (e.g. `\Device\Serial2`) and press "Search".
- The process that is owning the file should be selected.

If that doesn't help, please include a screenshot of the mapping in Virtualbox
of COM3 to the VM's COM1.